# Why ctrl+x+e is not working?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, editors

I've added `setenv EDITOR gvim` to .cshrc, but still no able to run `ctrl+x+e` to launch editor from terminal command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl+X+E</kbd> key combination would open the editor in `bash`, but not in `csh` (or `tcsh`) which you seem to be using.

You may bind <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to run your editor in `tcsh` using

```
bindkey -b -s C-X "$EDITOR\n"
```

This assumes that `EDITOR` has been previously set.

The `bindkey` command is not available in `csh`.

Comment: This works as a macro, which inputs "$EDITOR\n" into command line for you. If you have typed something before C-X, it would append $EDITOR to it and execute the whole commands. This is not exactly like the C-X C-E in bash.